# specify a generic and infer a generic in the same typescript function

Tags: typescript

I have the following function:

```
export const createStore = <
  OutputDocument extends Record<string, unknown>,
  Actions extends Record<string, unknown>,
>(
  inputDocument: Record<string, unknown>,
  actions: () => Actions,
): OutputDocument & Actions => {

  // this is actually a function that takes the input document and mutates it into `OutputDocument`
  const outputDocument = inputDocument as unknown as OutputDocument

  return Object.assign({}, outputDocument, actions())
}
```

I'm trying to get to the point where the return type is strongly typed. The issue is that I can either get the `OutputDocument` typed or the `Actions` typed, but not both.

If I provide the `OutputDocument` type (this is the case in my real application) then `Actions` is just `Record<string, unknown>`.

Basically what I want is given the following:

```
const test = createStore <{ output: string }>({ input: 'string here' }, () => ({ update: () => 'test' }))
```

I want the types of `test` to be:

```
{ output: string } & { update: () => string }
```

The function I have to mutate the input into the output has been very difficult to type, which is why I need to supply the types for the output document somehow.

Comment: Is that implementation a dummy? Because just declaring `inputDocument` to be an `OutputDocument` does not change any of its properties.

Comment: Also, what you try to get is currently not possible like this, because you can either not specify any generics or you have to specify all. See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).

Answer (score 0):

The function signature works as is, but you have to explicitly set all generics, because there is no way for the compiler to infer the return type and a [language limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) i.e.

```
const test = createStore<{ output: string }, { update: () => string }>(
  { input: 'string here' },
  () => ({ update: () => 'test' }),
);
```

Note that the implementation will not satisfy what the function claims, this will still return an object with the runtime type of

```
{ input: string, update: () => string }
```